# Alignment of elements using relative layout

Tags: android, xamarin, android-relativelayout

My problem is I want to keep 3 elements like Buttons for example I have used a `RelativeLayout` as parent and `LinearLayout` as it's child and given `android:weightSum="3"` and added 3 buttons as it's children. I have achieved the UI I want.
But here Comes the original problem When One of the Button Visibility state is gone. Elements not coming properly.

How Can I achieve even though when I hide one button other two need to adjust.

Please Provide the solution if you have.

[image: first image]

[image: secondimage]

```
Respective Code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3.0">
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="TAB1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="TAB 2"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="TAB 3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your UI after hide one button

Comment: set visibility to INVISIBLE so that this issue resolved. If you set Gone then it remove that space but if you set Invisible then it will only hide the UI but set the space as of weight you have set
eg . texview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: I will try @NrupParikh

Comment: ok @Nawin , if you share your layout then i will excetly understand your issue if this solution not work

Comment: That is not what I want Nrup..I have 3 buttons when middle one visibility is gone also other two need to adjust with parent

Comment: @Nawin show my bellow comment i think you want like this , that will adjust with parent

Comment: Just remove weightSum as I stated in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41378768/540317 and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the `android:weightSum` attribute, just assign `android:layout_weight=1` to every child.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1" .

Use `android:weightSum` if you want to define the maximum weight sum. **If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children.**

Code example:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
       <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
       <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
       <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use relative layout instead of linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="2"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="3"/>
```

if you set visibility gone for second button then you can achive this

Answer (score 0):

or you can programetically remove the text of second button and set transperent background for this , like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:weightSum="3">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button        
    android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:text="3"
    android:id="@+id/btnThree"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**android:visibility="invisible"** Set this attribute for middle view.
And make sure that your child view (i.e Button) width is set to `0dp`. Because you are using weight for width.

Try this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context="com.augmented.wiki.SplashActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_splash_btnImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_splash_btnImage1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_splash_btnImage2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```